# SQL To get count for a particular date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to count incomplete orders for particular date range

My query:

```
select COUNT(ORDER_ID)
from Atable
where
  ORDER_TYPE='INCOMPLETE' and   
  DATE BETWEEN '31-OCT-14' AND '07-NOV-14'
```

But DATE column is `TimeStamp`.

How can I use a wild-card and `between` together?

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using??

Comment: What datatype is your column "DATE"?

Comment: It matter which database you're using, are you using mysql, postgresql, litesql, oracle, etc?

Comment: Date column Data type is TIME STAMP and RDBMS is Oracle

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `timestamp` column with string literals like that, the `timestamp` is implicitly cast to `varchar`, and the comparison is performed lexicographically - which, of course, is not the behavior you want.
You can use the [`to_timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) to explicitly force the cast in the direction you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(ORDER_ID) 
FROM   atable 
WHERE  order_type = 'INCOMPLETE'  AND
       "DATE" BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('31-OCT-14', 'DD-MON-YY') AND 
                      TO_TIMESTAMP('07-NOV-14', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

EDIT:
According to the clarification in the comments, you need a `group by` clause to the results per day:

```
SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP("DATE", 'DD-MON-YY'), COUNT(ORDER_ID) 
FROM     atable 
WHERE    order_type = 'INCOMPLETE'  AND
         "DATE" BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('31-OCT-14', 'DD-MON-YY') AND 
                        TO_TIMESTAMP('07-NOV-14', 'DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY TO_TIMESTAMP("DATE", 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: It worked..But I want count in day wise.. 31-oct count is 10, 1-NOV count is 15 like wise

Comment: @VivekShankar you need a `group by` clause - see my edit with the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try with timestamp as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(ORDER_ID) 
FROM Atable 
WHERE ORDER_TYPE='INCOMPLETE' 
AND   DATE BETWEEN 2014-10-31 00:00:01 AND 2014-11-07 23:59:59
```